# Very unstable app in IOS9 angularjs 1.4.8 and cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova

Using my app in chrome pc or compiled in android all is going very well. This app was delivered to our clients in android and ios 5 months ago.

I was using angularjs 1.3.0 and all ok

Recently We changed angularjs to 1.4.8 and on IOS9 the App get unestable when change views.

We use ng-view and route service.

The strange behaviors now are in ios9 he app even start to change views or mixing various loaded templates from diferent views between routes   and stay superimposed some views. It looks like in transition angularjs don't unload views correctly.

Today we are going to restore to angularjs 1.3.0 and test in IOS9 in order to find out more.

We'll post here the results of our test for help other to figure out

Anybody notice this problem and have more info about it??

Thanks in advance

EDITED and add more points during my test:

1) This problems only ocurr in devices not in simulator, but simulator is running OS 8.2 on iphone 6 plus, and ipad air. This is because We must update Xcode (actual is 6.2 because We need update OS in MAC too) I don´t know if this update could help. At least if We update to last OS and Xcode the simulator must have same error than hardware.

2) I restore in my projects the AngularJS libs 1.3.0 again and my app go stable again in devices with OS 9.0.2 This fixed all the problems but Why, thought last version of AngularJS Would cover backward.

Beat (thanks for help) talked about a known issue with iOS9 and angularjs but does this mean that version of angularjs 1.3.0 is not affected by this issue?

3) could it be the libs I use with angularJS (I've update all of them) This are the libs: angular.min.js, angular-touch.min.js, angular-swipe.min.js, angular-route.min.js, angular-resource.min.js, angular-animate.min.js.

Any tip would be very helpfull. Thanks for help.

Comment: There is an known issue with iOS9 and angularjs afaik. You should take a look at your console with safari on remote debugging. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Thank for your help Beat, I will follow your advice and going to prepare a remote debugging in my cordova-xcode. 
I added more points  from my  tests, hope someone helps them for better figure out this type of error.